# How to mock navigation.useragent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am tesing a react project using jest and react-testing-library.

The project has different code for navigator.useragent contains android / mobile / blackberry .

To test the code, I have to mock the navigation.useragent.

How I can achieve the mocking.

Answer (score 6):

Got the solution

Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'userAgent', {value : "     "});